# Relative link in CSS

Tags: html, relative-url

I need help with one situation. I creat file structure :

- MainFolder

  - index.html
  - IMGfolder

    - bg.jpg
  - CSSfolder

    - style.css

I need link picture bg.jpg relative url in my CSS style file :

```
background-color: url('?');
```

I try

```
/img/bg.jpg
../img/bg.jpg
```

but, it's not working. Thanks for help :)

Comment: `IMGfolder`? Is it called like that or is it actually called `img`? Please include the actual _folder names_ in your file structure.

Comment: What is your *actual* folder structure? You say `img` and `IMGfolder`. Which is it? And what URL do you visit to view `MainFolder/index.html` in the browser?

Comment: Please check in the debugging tools: is your CSS file loaded? Which actual image path is being tried to load?

Comment: sorry, img mean IMGfolder, and i want to write it in style.css file.

Comment: @NorbertBago If the folder is called `IMGfolder` then `../img/bg.jpg` as stated in your question won't work. You have to use the actual folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some lines of php in your html using [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getcwd.php) to be sure your relative path is correct.

BTW: In UNIX systems:

- / refers to the root directory
- ./ refers to the current directory
- ../ refers to the directory, in which the current directory is